# Using rangeslider.js for an HTML5 audio time scrubber

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, slider

I am digging into the finer points of [Andre Ruffert's rangeslider.js](http://andreruffert.github.io/rangeslider.js/) and I am having difficulty into incorporating his code into controlling and reacting to a simple HTML5 audio element.

I see that you can programmatically change the value of the slider with the click of a button, but how would I link the audio to update automatically with the audio as it plays, and modify the audio by clicking and dragging the thumb of the slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/79ff562k/

This uses the `timeupdate` event to update the range slider.

However there are some quirks when you try to change the time while it is playing - sometimes it snaps back to where it was. I believe this is some sort of race condition, because as you are sliding the track, the `timeupdate` event would fire and change it back to the current time. To make it work properly, you probably need to introduce some additional logic like pausing the audio while the slider is being dragged.

Hope this helps!

Comment: that's what I was missing, the BIND. thank you.  Gold star for you.